# Biblatex: How to get year in parenthesis with /textcite & shorthand

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using shorthands for some of my citations and generally using \textcite to get the authors without parenthesis and the year in parenthesis. My problem is that for the references with a shorthand \textcite replaces the year with the shorthand for the first citation.

I would like the first citation to be formatted like this:
author (year, "hereafter" shorthand)

And the following:
shorthand

MWE:

```
\documentclass[british,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citetracker=true,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas = {hereafter}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{jd14,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {Some Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = {2014},
  shorthand = {JD14},
}
@article{jd13,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {No shorthand here},
  journal = {Some Other Journal},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{longcite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{longcite}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{longcite}
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{jd14} again \cite{jd14}.

  Just for comparison \textcite{jd13}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to adapt `textcite` rather than `cite`, for it looks more like the final result you are intending. The following produces citations as specified:

```
\documentclass[british,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citetracker=true,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas = {hereafter}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{jd14,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {Some Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = {2014},
  shorthand = {JD14},
}
@article{jd13,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {No shorthand here},
  journal = {Some Other Journal},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{%
                \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
                \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
            \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
            {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
            {}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{%
                \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
                \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
            \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
            {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
            {}%
            \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
        {\ifciteseen
            {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
            {\printnames{labelname}%
                \setunit{%
                    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
                    \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
                \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
                {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
                {}%
                \iffieldundef{labelyear}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}
                    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
                    \iffieldundef{shorthandintro}
                    {\printtext{\bibstring{citedas}}}
                    {\printtext{\printfield{shorthandintro}}}
                    \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}
                    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
                    \iffieldundef{shorthandintro}
                    {\printtext{\bibstring{citedas}}}
                    {\printtext{\printfield{shorthandintro}}}
                    \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{jd14} again \textcite{jd14}.

  Just for comparison \textcite{jd13}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which gives us:

[image]

You could probably simplify this, if the need to handle all cases of missing/present fields originally dealt with in the original `textcite` of the `authoryear` style is not a concern.

Comment: @Artturi Björk, I'm glad the solution worked for you. But do also take into consideration moewe's observations and suggestions. He's way more experienced in `biblatex` than I am, and if he offered a second (different) answer, it is likely he is seeing something I'm not.

Answer (score 2):

It can be beneficial to redefine `\cite` and not use `\textcite` if you want the standard placement of pre- and postnotes.

Try

```
\documentclass[british,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas = {hereafter}}

\newbibmacro*{shorthandintro:noparen}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthandintro}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \bibstring{citedas}\space
        \printfield{shorthand}}}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{shorthandintro}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:normal}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
  \printtext{\bibopenparen}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}%
        \printtext{\bibcloseparen}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}%
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro:noparen}%
     \printtext{\bibcloseparen}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{jd14,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {Some Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = {2014},
  shorthand = {JD14},
}
@article{jd13,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {No shorthand here},
  journal = {Some Other Journal},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{jd14} again \cite{jd14}.

  Just for comparison \textcite{jd13}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Doe, Smith and Bar (2014, hereafter JD14) again JD14. Just for comparison Doe, Smith and Bar (2013).]